# R mlogit segmentation of sample

Tags: r, multinomial

I'm using mlogit to analyze stated preference data from a survey of shoe purchasing habits.  I am currently running the following code:

```
library("mlogit") 

Running <- read.csv(file="DiscreteChoiceDatav3.csv", head=TRUE, sep=",")

RS <- mlogit.data(Running, choice="Selected", shape="long", alt.levels=c("1", "2", "3", "4"), id.var="ResponseID", varying=NULL)

m1 <- mlogit(Selected ~ Brand + Cushioning + Fit + LnPrice + EXP_Weight | 0 | 0, data=RS)  

summary(m1)
```

Which is generating these results, which I am satisfied with:

```
Call:
mlogit(formula = Selected ~ Brand + Cushioning + Fit + LnPrice + 
    EXP_Weight | 0 | 0, data = RS, method = "nr", print.level = 0)

Frequencies of alternatives:
      1       2       3       4 
0.26859 0.24571 0.24142 0.24428 

nr method
4 iterations, 0h:0m:1s 
g'(-H)^-1g = 6.77E-08 
gradient close to zero 

Coefficients :
                      Estimate Std. Error  t-value  Pr(>|t|)    
BrandAAA            -0.4072202  0.0559660  -7.2762 3.433e-13 ***
BrandBBB            -0.5661727  0.0634774  -8.9193 < 2.2e-16 ***
BrandCCC            -0.9346379  0.0575556 -16.2389 < 2.2e-16 ***
BrandDDD            -0.6891785  0.0600212 -11.4823 < 2.2e-16 ***
CushioningModerate   0.7806761  0.0535750  14.5716 < 2.2e-16 ***
CushioningSoft       0.4684838  0.0568556   8.2399 2.220e-16 ***
CushioningVery Soft  0.2816491  0.0727461   3.8717 0.0001081 ***
FitSnug              0.5565443  0.0469520  11.8535 < 2.2e-16 ***
FitTight             0.0280130  0.0509774   0.5495 0.5826506    
LnPrice             -0.3744333  0.0760356  -4.9245 8.460e-07 ***
EXP_Weight          -0.0214945  0.0015584 -13.7927 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Log-Likelihood: -5316.9
```

I now want to segment the sample into three fitness categories (Low / Medium / High) using prior demographic data I have about the respondents.  I have tried to do so by creating new segmented brand variables and also new dummy variables as shown in the following table:

[image]

However, I get 'computationally singular' errors if I attempt to run even the simplest models intended to help investigate how factors such as Brand value vary with respondent fitness:

```
> m1 <- mlogit(Selected ~ Brand + Brand_Medium | 0 | 0, data=RS)  
Error in solve.default(H, g[!fixed]) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.09477e-17
> m1 <- mlogit(Selected ~ Brand_Medium | 0 | 0, data=RS)  
Error in solve.default(H, g[!fixed]) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.06423e-17
```

Does anyone have any ideas about where I am going wrong?  Many thanks.